# How delete the last git commit after pushing to remote then pulling from remote master branch to local

Tags: git, github, version-control

I pushed my changes to remote branch, then realized that I was using a wrong GitHub username, so I tried to undo the commit, but without success. I read that I could just use `git reset HEAD^` 
had I not pushed my change to remote, but it didn't work as the commit has been made to remote repo already.

I used `git reset @~1` which made my local commit history go back to the very first one and erased the entire commit history after first one. And my goal was to commit only the last one, so I `git pull origin master` and `git fetch --all` to get the remote repo into my local, but it did not update commit history in local.

So what should I do:
1) to update my local commit history matched up to the remote history?
2) then commit my latest commit in remote repo?

Lastly, does it cause an issue if a different user delete a commit history (even though both belong to me anyway)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already pushed the changes you shouldn't really change the history of it. But if you really want to, now that you have reset your local repository to the state you want you can just run:

```
git push -f origin <branch name that you want to push>
```

The `-f` option forces the changes to the remote repository.

The proper way to do it is to revert the commit, which creates a new commit that is the inverse of the commit you are reverting, effectively erasing the changes you've made without changing history.

- first, get the `sha` of the commit you want to undo (it doesn't even need to be the last commit)
- run the command locally `git revert
- push the changes normally `git push origin <branch you want to push>`

Note, there is no force pushing here. There is no rewriting of history.

As for the difference in username, It makes little difference what user name or email you use. in your git configuration, because they are informational. You can change your name and email in your git config to whatever you like and it will show up in the git log. It's for this reason that you have the option to use GPG signing of your commits to really verify that the person who made that commit really is who they say they are. You can see a [description of signing here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/2796779828/signing-a-git-tag).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last commit locally, use:

```
git reset --hard id_penultimate_commit
```

To remove this same commit remotely, use:

```
git push --force
```